# jquery set selected attribute on an option using like

Tags: jquery

How can i set ubuntu selected from the following select box i tried the following below

```
<select>
<option value="val1">Val 1</option>
<option value="val2">Val 2</option>
<option value="val3">Val 3</option>
<option value="val3">Ubuntu -12.04 amd......</option>
</select>


$('#image_id').find('option[text="ubuntu"]').attr('selected');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
$('#image_id').find('option:contains("Ubuntu -12.04")').prop('selected',true);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7hABQ/15/)**

So as per your new request you can do like,

```
$('#image_id').find('option:contains("Ubuntu"):contains("-12.04")').prop('selected',true);
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7hABQ/17/)

Comment: can this be modified to conatins ubuntu and 12.04?

Comment: i want some thing like ubuntu and 12.04

Comment: Can u use a and clause here i want it like it conatains ubuntu and 12.04 see the edited question

Comment: Strange i still cannot see the option selected

Comment: @Rajeev you must be using ie 9 or 10, I think. because Milind's demo is utilizing jquery 1.10.. it would not support ie browsers.. check out the demo attached in the answer,

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your `select` has id value as `image_id`:

```
<select id="image_id">
```

then you can use **[:contains()](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)** selector:

```
$('#image_id').find('option:contains("Ubuntu")').prop('selected',true);
```

Note: `:contains` is case-sensitive , if you want to match `ubuntu` as well than you need to override the default `:contains()` method:

```
$.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
    return function( elem ) {
        return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s98ez/1/)**

Comment: why did you edit your post frm `option[text="Ubuntu"]` to `option:contains("Ubuntu")` ..? I was about to ask a doubt related to that..?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Because the OP want to check if the text contains substring not the entire text value

Answer (score 0):

I like to use .filter to gain more control over the finding process:

```
// Use the function overload for val
$("#image_id").val(function() {
    // Find the value of the option inside which matches the criteria
    return $(this).find("option").filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
        // Do a case-insensitive search for both "ubuntu" and "12.04"
        return text.indexOf("ubuntu") > -1 && text.indexOf("12.04") > -1;
    }).val();
});
```

[<kbd>jsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/PBLuh/2/)